# What's medial law?

Tags: abstract-algebra

While i'm reading about AG-groupoids, there is noted that identity
$$(xy)z=(zy)x$$
implies "medial law":
$$(xy)(uv)=(xu)(yv)$$

Can anyone tell me what is medial law? I cannot translate it to my language, but I'm highly interested what the "medial law" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition:  An LA-semigroup (also called Abel-Grassmann's groupoid) satisfies the medial law if $(ab)(cd) = (ac)(bd)$ for all $a,b,c,d$.

Reference: [Left almost semigroups defined by a free algebra](http://www.math.unl.edu/~s-minam1/la-semigroup.pdf)
.

Comment: For the meaning of "medial" see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial). The elements in the "middle" are interchanged.